# Convert pandas.offsets.CustomBusinessDay to numpy offset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have code that looks like this which gets an offset for a date:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
from datetime import datetime

biz_day_only= True
offset = 1
us_biz_days = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
dt = pd.to_datetime(['20231231', '20231031'])

d_offset = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(abs(offset), holidays=us_biz_days.holidays) if biz_day_only else pd.offsets.Day(abs(offset))
return (dt - d_offset) if offset < 0 else (dt + d_offset)
```

i get the following warning:

```
<string>:1: PerformanceWarning: Non-vectorized DateOffset being applied to Series or DatetimeIndex.
```

I am trying to fix that warning by using numpy:

```
new_dt = dt.values.astype('M8[D]') + np.timedelta64(d_offset, 'D')
```

I believe it is because d_offset is a Pandas offset.  How would i convert that a numpy offset?
I see that there is a `d_offset.n` property with an integer value.  is that safe to use? It has value of 1 in the above use case however, so it's not properly rolling forward the date to next business day when used.

Thanks

Comment: You have syntax error in your code (return outside function). Please [edit] your question and put there an example that shows the erroneous behavior).

Comment: @AndrejKesely fixed mismatched parens

Comment: also, updated it to use a series of dates as a single value (Timestamp) doesnt cause the issue

Answer (score 0):

It's not a numpy solution, but i was able to get rid of the warning using the following:

```
new_dt = dt.apply(lambda x: x + d_offset)
```